# Postgres is failing with 'could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map" '

Tags: macos, homebrew, postgresql

I'm having an issue with my install of postgres in my development environment and I need some help diagnosing it. I haven't yet had any luck in tracking down a solution.

1. I have postgres 9.0.4 installed with homebrew
2. I am running on OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)

I can start and stop the server

```
$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
server starting
```

If I try to stop though

```
$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
pg_ctl: PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid" does not exist
Is server running?
```

Ok this is missing

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/var/postgres/ | grep postmaster
$
```

But it is definitely running

```
$ ps aux | grep postgres
pschmitz   303   0.9  0.0  2445860   1428   ??  Ss    3:12PM   0:02.46 postgres: autovacuum launcher process       
pschmitz   304   0.9  0.0  2441760    428   ??  Ss    3:12PM   0:02.57 postgres: stats collector process       
pschmitz   302   0.0  0.0  2445728    508   ??  Ss    3:12PM   0:00.56 postgres: wal writer process       
pschmitz   301   0.0  0.0  2445728    560   ??  Ss    3:12PM   0:00.78 postgres: writer process       
pschmitz   227   0.0  0.1  2445728   2432   ??  S     3:11PM   0:00.42 /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.3/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres -r /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

And if I try to access or use it I get this.

```
$psql
psql: FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory
```

But global/pg_filenode.map definitely exists in

```
$ls -l /usr/local/var/postgres/

...
-rw-------  1 pschmitz  staff   8192 Sep 16 15:48 pg_control
-rw-------  1 pschmitz  staff    512 Sep 16 15:48 pg_filenode.map
-rw-------  1 pschmitz  staff  12092 Sep 16 15:48 pg_internal.init
```

I have attempted to uninstall and reinstall to no effect. Any ideas on how I can solve this?
It has pretty much prevented me from getting anything done today.

Comment: Does your log file (/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log) say anything useful about this?

Comment: Also it might be useful to see the whole contents of /usr/local/var/postgres/ if possible.

Comment: IMHO the directory /usr/local/var should be owned by postgres.postgres. Postgres cannot find them because of lack of access rights.

Comment: the log file wasn't particularly helpful.

Comment: does "psql -h localhost mydbname" work ?

Answer (score 33):

I am not sure what the source of my original problem was with 9.0.3 because I was getting this problem:

```
psql: FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory
```

However as stated above it turns out that the running process was for my previous postgres install of 9.0.3

I believe I had an old version org.postgresql.postgres.plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/

I had to:

1. Remove and re-add the launch agent
2. Kill the processes for 9.0.3
3. Initialize the db `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres`
4. Restart my computer

and now I have it up and working.

Comment: This also worked for me. Though I didn't need to do the first step.

Answer (score 29):

Encountered this problem using `mdillon/postgis:9.6` Docker image. Simple `sudo docker restart <container id>` solved the problem.

Comment: Wow, tried everything. I had removed the data file, and inserted a backup. Restarting the container (and thus the process) did the trick!

Comment: This suggest helps me. good one

Answer (score 16):

That may be a permission issue, check the owner and group of configuration files in /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/

```
chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/
```

Answer (score 8):

I just encountered this problem. Solved it by setting the owner of the postgres data directory to the unprivileged postgres user.

Comment: I used `sudo chown -R postgres /usr/local/var/postgres` to do this

Answer (score 5):

`ps aux | grep postgres` revealed I had another instance of postgres running on a temp data directory from a previous test run. Killing this process fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

My step-by-step solution in fedora:

- `/bin/systemctl stop  postgresql.service`  (Stop the service)
- `rm -rf /var/lib/pgsql/data`  (Remove the "data" direcotry)
- `postgresql-setup initdb`   (Recreate the "data" directory)
- `/bin/systemctl start  postgresql.service` (Start the service)

It is also useful to check the permissions of the "data" directory:

`chown -R postgres:postgres <path_to_data_dir>`

(Kudos to @LuizFernandodaSilva & [@user4640867](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28899016/2996101))

Answer (score 2):

I had an old value of PGDATA confusing things.

Answer (score 2):

This (https://gist.github.com/olivierlacan/e1bf5c34bc9f82e06bc0) solved my problem! I first had to:

1. Delete Postgres.app from my Applications
2. Delete /usr/local/var/postgres directory
3. `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres/`

Then I was able to start/stop Postgres with these 2 commands:

Start:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Stop:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem:

I am running postgresql-9.3

My plist file is in the following directory:/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.3.plist 

Step 1 will stop postgres 
1. $ sudo launchctl stop com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.3 
Start postgres using the following command (can find this location using $ brew info postgres) 
2. $ postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres

Answer (score 1):

I agree about all of the above solutions. I was running Postgres on a server, and the problem was that I was using a PORT number that was used by some other OLDER version of Postgres.

I only needed to change the port.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error `psql: FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory`.

Thanks for note #2 above: 'Kill the processes for 9.0.3'

I previously configured and compiled PostgreSQL.  I then decided to reconfigure, gmake, gmake install with different file paths. The newly compiled program wasn't finding 'pg_filenode.map' in the expected filepath.  Killing the running postgres process, emptying pgsql/data, and doing initdb again allowed creation of a new database.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to turn off you antivirus.
In my case when i turn off the antivirus(kaspersky) it worked fine
Ref : https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/610

Answer (score 0):

just grant permission using the command line:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*
```