# Postgresql server is running on local machine but psql can not connect

Tags: postgresql

After doing `brew install postgres`:

```
brew install postgres
brew link --overwrite postgresql
```

Postgres is already running:

```
/~ $brew services start postgresql
Service `postgresql` already started, use `brew services restart postgresql` to restart.
```

But then how do we connect using `psql` client?

```
13:47:28/~ $psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

**Updates**    Tried various suggestions.

Try restarting ..

```
 $brew services start postgresql
Service `postgresql` already started, use `brew services restart postgresql` to restart.
14:37:19/fastparquet $brew services restart postgresql
Stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)

14:37:39/fastparquet $psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
14:37:55/fastparquet $
```

Connect to localhost?

```
14:37:34/fastparquet $psql -h localhost
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Does `psql -h localhost` work?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27700596/330315  or https://stackoverflow.com/a/17411832/330315 if you are **really** sure that Postgres is indeed running

Comment: Postgres is clearly not running

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . Look like that is spot on.  pls make an answer: you can use my *update* in the OP for more details

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . Sure - but you have earned it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link from `a_horse_with_no_name` did the trick.  Specifically:

```
initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres/
```

(from [Homebrew postgres broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700596/homebrew-postgres-broken) )

and then

```
 createdb
```

(the latter from [psql: FATAL: database "<user>" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633422/psql-fatal-database-user-does-not-exist) )