# creating user with postgresql FATAL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I used brew to install postgresql, and also used install the pg Gem along with it. However, when i try running createuser databasename i get this error:

```
 createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory
```

I've tried completely uninstalling from brew, the gem and the /usr/local/var/postgres file and still doesn't work after i do a reinstall(strange thing is, when i do a reinstall and try to initdb, it says the file is not empty?)

a bit of google search and i found some solutions but i have no idea how to do them

1. Remove and re-add the launch agent
2. Kill the processes for 9.0.3
3. Initialize the db initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
4. Restart my computer

the last 2 instructions is pretty straight forward, but i have no idea how to do the first 2

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you came across [Postgres is failing with 'could not open relation mapping file “global/pg_filenode.map” '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445935/postgres-is-failing-with-could-not-open-relation-mapping-file-global-pg-fileno) To clarify the first two steps:

```
$ launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.postgresql
$ killall postgres
$ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

The caveats for the postgres formula have more info, which you can view with `brew info postgres`:

```
==> Caveats
If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed,
you may need to remove the previous version first. See:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/issue/2510

To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.3) of PostgreSQL, see:
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/upgrading.html

When installing the postgres gem, including ARCHFLAGS is recommended:
  ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg

To install gems without sudo, see the Homebrew wiki.

To reload postgresql after an upgrade:
    launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```