# rails application on docker-compose: db:migration shows "Permission denied"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, database-migration

I'm running a rails app on docker-compose image. After I created a user devise, when I run `docker-compose run web rails db:migrate` it shows the following error: `PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": Permission denied`

I have tried all the solutions rails and psql related, so I'm guessing my problem is with the docker-compose program somehow, I also tried with `sudo` but the result is the same

Code:
The command I run is `docker-compose run web rails db:migrate` after `docker-compose run web rails g devise usuario`

and this is the output:

```
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": Permission denied
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
```

Rest of the log in this link:
https://hastebin.com/axiboxohem.bash

Answer (score 8):

It turned out that somehow there were multiple containers of the same image on Docker. I could see the extra containers mounted with `docker ps -a -q`, and removed them with `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`. That did it for me, I guess one of the containers was holding to the file.

Comment: I faced the same problem, and run `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

your problem seems to be just in the connection with Postgresql, check out your postgres service is up or if you have the right permission in the folder.
Look this, maybe help: [Postgres is failing with 'could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map" '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445935/postgres-is-failing-with-could-not-open-relation-mapping-file-global-pg-fileno)

Answer (score 0):

Run `docker stop $(docker ps -q)` to stop all running containers and try again.